# Como asignar colores especificos en ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos y quiero hacer un barplot en el que cada columna está relacionada con una variable, y quiero asignar a cada columna un color especifico, y no el elegido por defecto por ggplot.

Estos son los datos que tengo:

```
    Abstencion    PP    PSOE    IU    UPyD   Ahora.madrid Ciudadanos Year
1      40.86     27.79  20.20  5.72   0.00         0.00       0.00  a91
2      28.87     37.35  19.62 11.02   0.00         0.00       0.00  a95
3      39.94     29.54  21.49  5.17   0.00         0.00       0.00  a99
4      31.07     35.21  25.18  4.95   0.00         0.00       0.00  a03
5      34.09     36.48  20.28  5.69   0.00         0.00       0.00  a07
6      32.78     32.79  15.79  7.09   5.18         0.00       0.00  a11
7      31.15     23.62  10.44  1.16   1.25        21.76       7.81  a15
```

Lo que quiero es hacer un barplot en función del año, y que cada columna sea del color del partido.

Para ello, tengo este vector con los colores:

```
col <- c("black","dodgerblue","firebrick1","chartreuse3",
         "deeppink","darkorchid3","darkorange1")
```

Y he creado este codigo (suponiendo que la matriz anterior se llama X). Soy nuevo en ggplot asi que tal vez haya una forma mejor de hacerlo:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
a <- X[1,]
a.molten <- melt(a, value.name="Votes", variable.name="Party")
#Eliminar los partidos politicos que sacaron 0 votos
a.molten <- a.molten[-which(a.molten$Votes==0),] 
ggplot(a.molten, aes(x=Party, y=Votes, fill=Party)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

cambiando el parametro de a <- X[i,] consigo los barplots de cada año, pero lo que me falta ahora es saber como asignar a cada partido el color recogido en el vector col

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar especificar colores dados por `fill` debes usar y agregar `scale_fill_manual(values = col)` para el relleno. Además puedes usar `color` junto a `scale_color_manual(values = col)`para modificar los bordes.

Los colores se agregarán siguiendo el orden de los factores de la variable `Party`.

```
ggplot(a.molten, aes(x=Party, y=Votes, fill=Party,  color=Party)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col)
```